# DataFrame.loc results in string objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below.

```
df = 

        A           B
        
1.0     4.0         45.0
2.0     4.0         11.2
3.0     49.2        10.8
```

When I select a particular row using `loc`:

```py
df.loc[1.0][['A','B']]
```

The above line of code results in the following:

```
A    4.0
B    45.0
Name: 1.0, dtype: object
```

I want to represent these values in a tuple. Therefore, I do the following:

```py
tuple(df.loc[1.0][['A','B']])
```

which gives me a result `('4.0', '45.0')` which indicates the values inside the tuple are of type string. How do I convert it to float? That is I want the result to look like
`(4.0, 45.0)`.

I tried to convert the value before representing it as tuple. For example :  `df.loc[1.0]['A'].astype(float64)` and it resulted in the following error.
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `df.loc[1.0, ['A','B']]` is `Series` is possible change values to floats:

```
tuple(df.loc[1.0, ['A','B']].astype(float))
```